# Logical operations in cout

Tags: c++, cout

Consider:

```
int i = 56, j = 0;
int n = i&&j;
cout << i&&j;
cout << endl << n;
```

whose output would be:

```
56
0
```

I imagine it's either because of operator precedence or logical short circuit, but I can't seem to figure out which, or the reason.

Comment: If it's operator precedence then `cout << (i&&j)` should give the expected result.

Comment: "the output would be" ??

Comment: And a simple google/duckduckgo/… search for the two keywords you already know was not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `cout << i&&j` is equivalent to `(cout << i) && j`. Both operands are evaluated and converted to `bool`. The statement as a whole has no effect, but the evaluation of the subexpression `cout << i` has the usual side effects, of course, namely writing something to the standard output.

The `&&` operator is indeed short-circuited and `j` is only evaluated if `cout << i` evaluates as `true`. This condition is equivalent to `cout.good()`, which is usually the case (unless you somehow managed to close your standard output).

Comment: So as I now understand it, (cout << i) would return a reference so the expression would become 1&&0, which would evaluate to 0, but since cout has already happened, then even though the logical expression executes, there are no visible output on the console. If this is the correct understanding, thank you very much for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

As you expected, the `<<` operator comes takes precedence over `&&`.

Thus, `cout << i&&j` first outputs i, then compares the returned stream to j (both are true, so the returned value is true, but this value is discarded).

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for the full list of operator precedence.