# Why does this program not output a boolean value?

Tags: c++, integer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a = 8;
    cout << "ANDing integer 'a' with 'true' :" << a && true;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this program output `8` and not `1` (for `true`)?

Comment: Are you questioning operator precedence and evaluation?

Comment: I want to know why the output is 8.

Comment: It is logical operator so how it calculates

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what is desired, compile and running a code is something you can do before requesting assistance with the code itself. Just to answer your question, the output is: ANDing integer 'a' with 'true' :8

Comment: If you rewrite the question ('why' instead of 'what') and add a bit of context, I don't think it is such a bad question.

Comment: Note:  if you use parenthesis, you get a different answer:  `(a && true)`.

Comment: The question isn't bad guys. Don't downvote so heavily, especially on a new user.

Comment: @Pi It was pretty bad before the edit. It appeared heavily of "do this homework for me." After the clarification by the OP that the question is about *why*, not *what*, it's not that bad

Comment: @Justin You are perfectly right!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26952726/1896169

Answer (score 7):

If you look at [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), you will find that the left-shift operator `<<` has a higher precedence than the logical AND operator `&&`.

As such, it is evaluated as:

```
(cout << "ANDing integer 'a' with 'true' :" << a)  &&  true;
```

which prints 8.

Answer (score 3):

In the expression `8 && true` 8 is evaluated first (and in this turn also streamed). Than true is evaluated and the operator returns true after that. But than the 8 is already in the stream. If you put `(8 && true)` instead, the parentheses are evaluated first and the result is guarantreed to be 1, which then is streamed.

This behavior is called [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) - which describes the order in which the operators are executed (in your case `&&` and `<<`).

Answer (score 3):

The logical AND operator, `&&`, works with expressions.
The first expression is evaluated.
If the first expression is false, no more evaluations.
Otherwise the second expression is evaluated.
Next, the result of the two Boolean expressions is returned.

So, the first expression is evaluated:

```
cout << "ANDing integer 'a' with 'true' :" << a
```

A side effect of the evaluation is the following output to the console:

```
ANDing integer 'a' with 'true' :8
```

Your output is generated because it is a side-effect of evaluating the first expression.

Answer (score 1):

The logical AND operator `&&` works with expressions. If both are true returns true and false if otherwise.

```
cout << "ANDing integer 'a' with 'true' :" << a && true;
```

is being evaluated as:

```
(cout << "ANDing integer 'a' with 'true' :" << a)  &&  true;
```

due to operator precedence (`<<` having higher precedence than AND `&&`)
giving you the print of: `8`
if we do the following change: `(a && true);`
it will give you the print of: `1`

Comment: This is not what is going on! -1   Please modify to explain correctly what is going on, and I will remove downvote.

Comment: @user4581301 You could be right. After rephrasing I will def. remove downvote. Right now its locked in.

Comment: @Pi sorry my bad, maybe I made some mistake, will check my answer and edit to avoid being misleading. Thanks for the feedback